# NoSuchElement exception is not coming when webElement not found in a page in webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

NoSuchElement exception is not coming when webElement not found in a page in webdriver

when webelement is available in a page, all the operation done on that webelement will work, but if the webelement is not available in that page, then ideally when we do any operation on that webelement it should throw a exception. But for me no exception is coming and the test does not respond , even on debugging it does not respond at that place.

Can anyone tell me y this is happening ?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try by setting implicit timeout for finding the element

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("element_id"));
    System.out.println("Element Found");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Element Not Found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Divi, it worked :). Actually I have setup implicit time limit quite more in setup method, I think thats y it was not throwing exception that time, now it throws exception for pagefactory element also, Thanks again Divi.

Comment: Ok fine I am happy to hear that I can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are '***asserting***' the element presence in a '**Try/Catch**' block before you are taking actions on it. General practice (what I follow and many I know do) is to assert the element presence and then do action on it(if true).

Something like -

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        System.out.println("Element Present");
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Element absent");
        return false;
    }
}
```

might solve the issue for you!

Comment: Just curious, why the case is - one time the WebElement is present and other times its not. I mean may be you need new test case for the later situation.

Comment: Maitreya,

I am using PageFactory in webdriver. So am using @Findby to get the webelement , then i am using the webelemnet in methods .

so answer is no am not using try /catch to get the element.

am i supposed to do that in Page Factory?

Comment: I guess you can use it. (After all it's Java!!)
You may have to write your own function like isElementPresent() to assert element present before you carry out your actions. Edited answer to add a default isElementPresent function.

Comment: For page factory example - http://iainrose.tumblr.com/post/28060274976/using-by-objects-to-verify-if-webelement-present

Comment: You might get surprised, I tried driver.findelement() also in try catch, and it did the same thing. I am not sure what is wrong. am using webdriver, maven and testng for my project. some of my dev friend told might be ur maven extension got corrupt, so i tried again with a new project with modified dependencies like selenium version from 2.25 to 2.24.1 in pom.xml but result has no difference

Answer (score 1):

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "someCssSelector")]
IWebElement element;

  public static bool IsElementPresent(IWebElement element)
        {
            try
            {
                return element.Displayed;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The above code worked out for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import:
**import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException**;

Don't import *java.util*